# Bootstrap table editable on icon click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap table in my react application.I want to have a functionality like this: In each row I want an edit icon which when I click, it should make all the row elements editable. Currently I have table like this

```
<Table className='flags-table' responsive hover>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th> Time In</th>
                        <th> Time Out</th>
                        <th> Type</th>
                        <th> Category</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {
                        that.props.tag_fetch_reducer.tags.map((x, i) => (
                            <tr key={i} onClick={this.handleRowClick.bind(this, i)}>
                                <td>
                                    <div className='red-box'></div>
                                </td>
                                <td> {x.frame_in} </td>
                                <td> {x.frame_out} </td>
                                <td> {x.tagname} </td>
                                <td> {x.category}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
```

How can I make it editable?

Comment: Did my answer help you to move in right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide the whole code for your editable table but I can certainly show you a way to achieve this.

If you want, you can provide a table where all the columns will be disabled input boxes. So When use clicks on edit icon, all those disabled input fields will get enabled and then you can edit those fields. You can store disabled and enabled state in react or redux state.

```
that.props.tag_fetch_reducer.tags.map((item, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value={item.frame_in} disabled={this.isDisabled(index)}/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value={item.frame_out} disabled={this.isDisabled(index)} />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value={item.tagName} disabled={this.isDisabled(index)} />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value={item.category} disabled={this.isDisabled(index)} />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button onClick={this.handleRowClick.bind(this, index)}>
            Edit
        </button>
    </td>
 </tr>
);
```

Where `isDisabled` is a function, which will look into current state to check whether the field at particular index is disabled or not.

Or, if you don't like the above approach. You can create a table as below.

```
that.props.tag_fetch_reducer.tags.map((item, index) => (
  <tr key={index}>
    <td>
      {item.id}
      <input type="text" value={item.frame_in} style={this.showStyle(index)}/>
    </td>
    <td>
      {item.name}
      <input type="text" value={item.frame_out} style={this.showStyle(index)} />
    </td>
    <td>
      {item.name}
      <input type="text" value={item.tagName} style={this.showStyle(index)} />
    </td>
    <td>
      {item.name}
      <input type="text" value={item.category} style={this.showStyle(index)} />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button onClick={this.handleRowClick.bind(this, index)}>
        Edit
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
);
```

In this approach, you can keep display part and editing part separate from each-other. 
Here, At the beginning style for all input fields will be `display: 'none'`. Now, when user clicks on edit button. You can change the style of that particular row and make all input fields at particular row visible.

Apart from this, if you don't want to provide editable table then you can create a separate component for editing. When user clicks on edit icon, new component will be displayed in which user can edit all those fields and hit submit to persist all those updated fields.

That's all I can say.

With quick google search I found some resources that can certainly help you.

[React Data Grid Examples](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html)

[Editable react table example on JSFiddle](http://codepen.io/Shamiul_Hoque/pen/LNavdZ) and [explanation](http://jsfiddle.net/shoque/eauhzgoL/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: what will the handleRowClick function do (in first case)? Can you please add isDisabled and handleRowClick function's code in answer? Would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: As you can see `handleRowClick` function takes index value as an argument. It will set a boolean value true for passed index. So when the component will render, `this.isDisabled(index)` will return false and fields will be editable for that index.

Comment: http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/all-features in this example the country edit option gives me a list of option to choose from. Can I do it in my table also? How?

Comment: It's available as a npm module. You can use it if you want. [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-grid)

Comment: It is react-data-grid and I am using bootstrap table.

Comment: I just want to show a drop down in columns instead of edit text box.

Comment: Then you ust need to replace edit-test box with dropdown. For that You can use react-bootstrap `FormControl` with componentClass `select` as `<FormControl componentClass="select" >` or normal `<select> ...</select>`. It's totally upto you.

Comment: Ok I ll do that. Also regarding the first case u suggested in solution. I need to execute some other function when I click on row as a whole and execute the edit button click function when edit button is clicked. How can I do that. Currently when I click edit, the row also gets clicked a whole.

Comment: And it also screws my css  of table. The whole thing gets expanded in width